# Python search and replace ip address

Tags: python, search, replace

I want to use re.sub to search and replace whatever ip address with specific ip address using Python 
For example in file has

`address = 192.168.1.1` or `address = 1.1.1.1` or `address = fe0c::1` The keyword is `address =`, rest of is wildcard. I want to convert to `address = 2.2.2.2` or `address = f870:2:2:2::1` . The destination is specific address. It seemed to me use re.sub simple, but I do not mind to use others

Thanks

Tom

Comment: Have you tried to concoct a pattern?  There are a lot of online python regex *helpers*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#line is whatever string you're trying to replace
re.sub("address = \S+", "address = 2.2.2.2", line)
```

You call `re.sub` with 3 parameters: `re.sub(pattern, replacement, string_to_replace)`, where `pattern` is a regular expression indicating what you want to replace.

In our case the pattern is `"address = \S+"`, which is saying match the characters `"address = "` followed by 1 or more non-whitespace chars. When re finds a part of the string matching this pattern, it replaces that string with what we put in the `replacement` parameter, i.e. `"address = 2.2.2.2"`.

([link to docs on python's regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html))

Comment: Uh, "line" does not represent the string you're trying to replace. It represents a line in a file.

Comment: By "string you're trying to replace", I meant the string that's being altered (i.e. the string you want to replace with an alternate version). Which yes, in this case is a line in a file. But I can see how it would be an easily misinterpreted comment.